# Why I can't access a JavaScript function defined in a .js file from another .js file?

Tags: javascript, html

I am pretty new to JavaScript, and I was experimenting with the global scope following a tutorial.

In this tutorial I have 3 files:

1) **index.htm**:

```
<html>
    <head></head>

    <body>
        <h1>HELLO WORLD !!!</h1>

        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <script src="utility.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see I include 2 JavaScript files.

2) **app.js**:

```
var person = 'Torny';   // When I call the logPerson() function this line override the person variable value into the global stack

//console.log(person);

logPerson();
```

3) **utility.js** in which is defined the **logPerson()** function defined into the **app.js** file:

```
var person = 'Steve';

function logPerson() {
    console.log(person);
}
```

Ok, so I expected the following behavior:

Into the **app.js** file set the string 'Tony' as value of the **person** variable, the call the **logPerson()** function declared into the **utility.js** file and so print 'Tony' in the console.

The problem is that when I try to open the **index.htm** file into FireFox, I go into FireBug console and instead the 'Tony' value I obtain this error message:

```
ReferenceError: logPerson is not defined
```

So it seems that from the **app.js** file it can't see the **logPerson()** function that is defined into the **utility.js** file and imported.

Why? What am I missing? what is wrong?

Comment: The function call in app.js is made to the time where utility.js (and the functions within) is not known.  `Include order matters`

Comment: Yeah those scripting languages like order.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In javascript the order of the files matters. You need to load the script which defines your function before you can use it. Switch the 2 `<script>` tags

```
<body>
    <h1>HELLO WORLD !!!</h1>

    <script src="utility.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

change

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="utility.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="utility.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

;) You try to get definitions from a script which is loaded later
greetings

Answer (score 3):

First browser will parse the JS files.

If you see the order of script included

1. app.js
2. utility.js

So when it is parsing app.js. It sees `logPerson()` which is a function call not function definition. At this point of time the file utility.js is not parsed and the browser is not aware of that function also. (meaning till it reads utility.js).

So to solve this, call the logPerson api after dom-loaded, usiing body `onload` function.

Answer (score 2):

The explanation is as simple as that Javascript code is *interpreted* on the fly: As one script is loaded, it is executed immediately.

So, you just have to declare the scripts in the right order of dependence.

Answer (score 2):

You run the script which tries to use `logPerson` before you run the script that defined `logPerson`.

If you reverse the order of the scripts, it will work.

Function declaration hoisting only works within a given script.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it wasn't the `<script>` ordering that was the issue (as initially thought), but the scope in which the function was defined. To enable access of the function in other JS files, I made it a property of the object that *is* in the scope of those files. So now, it can be accessed as `MyObject.myFunction` wherever `MyObject` is instantiated.

```
(function ($) {
    function MyObject(data) {
        var myFunction = function(){
            console.log('');
        }

        $.extend(this, {

              // methods
              "myFunction": myFunction,

        });
    }
}(jQuery));
```